# what is 'jar' syntax means?

Tags: gradle

I recently started to learn Gradle and Groovy. And i have some questions about build.gradle syntax.

Basically build script file use groovy script as far as i know.
For example,

```
task hello {
    println 'hi!'
}
```

This syntax equals to

```
task('hello', {-> println('hi!');});
```

so, what this syntax equals to?

```
jar {// this part. i couldn't figure it out.
    manifest {
        attributes 'Title': 'something'
    }
    /* this will be
     * 
     * manifest(['Title': 'something']);
     */

    // blah blah
}
```

Comment: It means "create  a JAR file with a manifest that includes a "Title" attribute.

Comment: What specifically are you asking? How DSLs work in Groovy?

Comment: @DaveNewton What if i translate this syntax to java style, what it looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java code might look like (see [Jar API Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.html#manifest(Closure%3C?%3E)) and [Manifest API Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/java/archives/Manifest.html))

```
Jar jar = project.getTaskByName('jar')
jar.configure((Jar task) -> {
     task.manifest((Manifest manifest) -> {
         Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
         map.put('Title', 'something');
         manifest.attributes(map);
     });
});
```

In general, Groovy is just a syntactical sugar for underlaying methods.

Comment: actually what i wanted is not this but thanks. i want full-syntax of that code. i mean, groovy can omit some code like semicolon, paren etc. so i want a not-omitted code to understand how the script actually works like task method i wrote in my question.

Comment: ok, in that case the missing piece is `methodMissing('jar', {...})`. see e.g. http://mrhaki.blogspot.cz/2009/11/groovy-goodness-create-dynamic-methods.html

Comment: than "jar {}" is used to call "jar" method and there is no "jar" method actually. and somewhere there would be implementation of  'methodMissing'. am i right?

Comment: I believe the method is on the Project class or there will be some base script class having the method but I dont know by heart. Also I think the script is processed by AST transformation which may change how the actual method call looks like

Comment: I found some information about that. _The tasks of the project. A method is added for each task, using the name of the task as the method name and taking a single closure or Action parameter. The method calls the Task.configure(groovy.lang.Closure) method for the associated task with the provided closure. For example, if the project has a task called compile, then a method is added with the following signature: void compile(Closure configureClosure)._ ;D